# Sending OutputStream to browser and let browser save it

Tags: jsf, richfaces, export-to-excel

I want to export Data from a Rich Faces Data Table I have created outputStream from the data in the Data Table. Now want to send this OutputStream to browser and let it save. How can I do this?

`FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH));`

`OutputStream out = myMthodToCreateOutPutStream();`

Now how to save this `out` to browser   .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not clear where you are reading your data from. You need to create an InputStream to read the data.

Then, you first need to set the response headers to

```
HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=datafile.xls");
```

Use whatever filename you need.

Then set the mime-type:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Use the mime-type you need.

Then need to use the response object to get its outputstream -

```
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

Now write to it:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int len = -1;

//Write the file contents to the servlet response
//Using a buffer of 4kb (configurable). This can be
//optimized based on web server and app server
//properties
while ((len = inStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buf, 0, len);
}

outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Comment: This ans gives me a Hint to solve my problem.. Thanks alot